# LibGDX collision with rectangle and circle

Tags: libgdx, collision-detection

I have 2 objects, A and B, both are classes with only values, so positions and dimensions are only values (float posX,posY).

I have a render class which render A and B with shapeRenderer; A is rendered as a rectangle and B as a circle, how could check if there is a collision ?

**edit:**  I have a rectangle coming from up, when it hits the circle I have to stop the game

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use to check collision between circle / rectangle. Note that this doesn't do  `continuous collision detection`. Which means that if both of the *shapes are unproportionally small* or the objects are colliding with *really high speeds* (because you have too low fps and you use Delta Time to calculate the velocity for example), then the collision won't be detected.

```
static public Boolean CircleRectCollision(Vector2 circleCenter, Vector2 rectCenter, 
    float radius, float width, float height)
{
    float distanceY = Math.Abs(circleCenter.Y - rectCenter.Y);
    if (distanceY > (height / 2 + radius)) return false;

    float distanceX = Math.Abs(circleCenter.X - rectCenter.X);
    if (distanceX > (width / 2 + radius)) return false;

    if (distanceX <= (width / 2)) return true;
    if (distanceY <= (height / 2)) return true;

    float a = distanceX - width / 2;
    float b = distanceY - height / 2;
    float cSqr = a * a + b * b;
    return (cSqr <= (radius * radius));
}
```

Comment: My objects are moving. Could Intersector  help?

Comment: [ContantListener](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ContactListener.html) does continuous collision detection if bodies are `bullets`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988841/detect-collision-between-two-bodies-in-box2d-and-libgdxandroid) is also helpful for how to check collisions in Box2D libgdx. However, you still haven't described how your game looks like. I would assume you probably don't need a whole physics library for just a collision. Make sure that you *need* continuous collision before you use that library.

Comment: I am going to edit my question

Comment: @user65825 That image doesn't really explain a lot. Because I don't know how many pixels that is and how fast the objects are moving. Just try and see if it works for you. Try use a bit higher speed than usual to test it. Your objects need to be really small or move really fast for my function to not identify the collision.

Comment: Your code works, I only changed one thing because I had to adapt to my game. Thank you so much! Marked as best answer.

Comment: @user65825 what is that ? vector2 ?

Comment: It was in distanceX, in my case I have to check Y too

Comment: @user65825 I check in Y too, the algorithm works for any rectangle and circle. Ive been using it for months. Read it carefully

Comment: Can your function calculates circle to side rectangle collision too? Also what is rectCenter?
Is it rectangle center? If so, how do you calculate that and what is the width and height argument?
Is it the rectangle width and height? I